# StackOverflowError and random numbers

Tags: java, random, error-handling

I have a collection: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] from which I need to generate a random number of unique elements e.g. 5, 3, 7, 9, next time: 4, 8. My function works well but sometimes throws StackOverflowError because of recursive call on a function that generates random numbers and checks if there is no duplicates already. I wonder how I can  prevent this from happening.

Comment: I think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842533/generating-random-unique-data-takes-too-long-and-eats-100-cpu) should help. I had faced a similar issue earlier.

But I feel you should post some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a StackOverflowError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do this without using recursion. A rough sketch of an algorithm that might work better:

1. Create an empty list
2. Go through the source array and add each element with 50% probability to the list
3. Convert the list to an array
4. Use Arrays.shuffle() on the array to randomly reorder the elements

That should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use iteration (a `for` or `while` loop) rather than recursion.

Another solution is to start by making a mutable copy of your collection, and whenever you select an element from it, *remove* that element so that there's no risk of re-selecting it. (But be sure you're making an actual copy of your collection, e.g. `new ArrayList<Integer>(originalCollection)`, so that you aren't removing elements from the original.)

Answer (score 0):

Each element in your full list is either present or absent in a particular collection of elements.  That tells us to use binary.

`0b000000000` maps to [ ] i.e. all numbers absent.

`0b111111111` maps to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] i.e. all numbers present.

Any number between the two, treated as binary, will map to a subset of the whole collection.

`0b001010101` maps to [3, 5, 7, 9]

Each binary number in the range will map to a unique subset.  Your examples imply that ordering might be important.  If it is then you will have to deal with it separately.  This method will give you up to 2^9 = 512 different combinations.